# This Realm instance has already been closed, making it unusable

Tags: android, realm

When I perform some test in several devices, I got such error in several devices (5%-10%). I cannot find steps how to reproduce it, but I want to note that I have only one main Activity and a lot of fragments. I've opened only one realm instance in onCreate() method and closed it in onDestroy() method.

Class where I created a single instance:

```
private static Realm realm = null;

public static Realm getInstance(){
    if(realm == null || realm.isClosed())
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    return realm;
}
```

I set up realm config in Application class. Code of main Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    RealmBuilder.getInstance();
    RealmBuilder.getStaticRealmInstance(getApplicationContext());

    ...
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    RealmBuilder.getInstance().close();
}
```

I don't close realm instance in other places in the main thread. Do you know why I get sometimes this error?

Comment: Your method isn't thread safe for one. Also there shouldn't be a need for such a pattern. Realm already handles caching for you, so just doing `Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()` would also work and be just as performant.

Comment: it's necessary because I faced with issue that " Too many open files in io_realm_internal_". Because of it I created this pattern.

Comment: " Too many open files in io_realm_internal_" this will be fixed in `v1.1.1` which will be released very soon. And if you meet " Too many open files in io_realm_internal_" with only one `RealmConfiguaration`, that probably means you have some Realm instance in background thread is not closed properly.